# Homology group of $(X,X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $H$ be a homology theory.

I want to show that $H(X,X) = 0 \; \forall p\in\Bbb Z$. Maybe someone can tell me whether my reasoning is correct.

From the exactness axiom I get a long exact sequence:
$$... \xrightarrow{\text{$\partial_*$}} H_p(X) \xrightarrow{\text{$i_*$}} H_p(X) \xrightarrow{\text{$j_*$}} H_p(X,X)  \xrightarrow{\text{$\partial_*$}}...$$

where $i_*$ is the map induced by the inclusion (identity in this case) $i:X\rightarrow X$. Therefore $i_* = id_*:H_p(X) \rightarrow H_p(X)$.

$j_*$ is induced by $id:X\rightarrow (X,X)$. Therefore $j_* = id_*$. Since this is a LES we have that $im(i_*)=ker(j_*)$, but $im(i_*)=H_p(X)$ and therefore $j_*$ sends everything to $0$. But $j_*$ is also the identity.

$\Rightarrow H_p(X,X) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $j_*$ is induced by $id:X\to(X,X)$. Therefore $j_*=id_*$

This does not make sense.

The fact that you need to use is that, in the following sequence if the middle arrow is an isomorphism, then the other two arrows are $0$.

$A \to B \to C \to D$

In particular, in the LES,

$\cdots \xrightarrow{j_*} H_{n+1}(X, X) \xrightarrow{\partial_*} H_n(X) \xrightarrow{id_*} H_n(X) \xrightarrow{j_*} H_n(X, X) \xrightarrow{\partial_*} H_{n-1}(X) \xrightarrow{id_*} \cdots$

the maps $\partial_*$ and $j_*$ are zero, or that they factor through $0$. So, the following is exact:

$0 \to H_n(X, X) \to 0$

Comment: thanks! btw i also thought id:X-->(X,X) doesn't make sense, but isn't that how j_* is defined?

Comment: @Ton910 the map $j_*$ is instead induced by $j:(X,\emptyset)\to (X,X)$ which is not the identity and thus $j_*$ might not be (and, in this case, isn't) an identity.

Answer (score 2):

Too much work!

By definition the chain complex $C_*(X,A)$ is, degreewise, the quotient $C_q(X)/C_q(A)$.

So $C_q(X,X) = C_q(X)/C_q(X) = 0$. Therefore the chain complex $C_*(X,X)$ is zero in every degree. Therefore its homology is zero.

Comment: Right but he doesn't say singular homology. Just a homology theory, probably satisfying the Eilenberg Steenrod axioms.

Comment: Not all homology theories are given by kernel-mod-image of some chain complex.

Comment: Yes, i just looked up the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms and that's what we defined in the lecture. I don't think we defined chain complexes for general homology theories. But does this work for general homology theories too?